# Can not run vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests on Command line in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, mftf, tests

When I run this command line `vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests` in Magento root it shows me an error :

> in **ModuleReSovlver.php** line 444:
>
> Could not retrieve API from Magento instance <403 Forbidden>

Anyone can help me a hand, please? I do not know what the problem here?

Comment: possible to check permission issue or htaccess if all are okay, than check your api headers.

Comment: It's okay, but when I run it on the window it cannot work